# App Engine requests being duplicated

Tags: java, google-app-engine

In examining my appengine logs, I discovered today that nearly all of my requests are being executed multiple times.  The two executions tend to be queued around 100 mS apart.  Aside from presumably doubling load on my app, this is causing some other problems.  Is anyone else experiencing this?  Typically the first request returns a 200, and the second, a 204.  The browser ID field is also blank on the second request.  Is there a resolution, or is this a Google bug?

Comment: Well, as to the `browser ID field is also blank on the second request` - That's because a 204 response means "that the request was received and understood, but that there is no need to send any data back". Not sure *why* the 2 requests are happening, though.

Comment: Check the HTTP Headers for the 2 requests in your App Engine logs. Do you similar values for all the header entries i.e. IP, Agent, etc.

Comment: Have you reviewed the appstats logs for your application in addition to the appengine logs? They may provide further insight: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/appstats

Comment: Have you got pagespeed enabled ?

Comment: Yes, I do have pagespeed enabled.  That seems to have been the basic problem.  It was not supposed to be processing the requests in question, but it turned out that my exceptions only applied to http, not https.  I made the change, the duplicate requests disappeared, and the server load fell by about half.  I suppose that resolves the problem.  Sorry to have thrown a red herring in front of you all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic problem turned out to be pagespeed.  Pagespeed requests generate two log entries - one when pagespeed is hit, and one when the server processes the request.  I had pagespeed configured incorrectly, so it was handling requests that should have been sent directly to the server.  This produced the duplicate log entries.